# Legs stops kicking while inhaling air during freestyle swiming

Tags: swimming, water-sports, freestyle

I have newly started learning swimming, major problem which I am facing and my coach informs me is that my legs stops kicking while I am taking breath while doing freestyle swimming.
Because of this my legs sinks and I need to put lot of efforts to bring them up.

I am not sure how to make sure that both my hands and legs are working together and not only one at a time. How to concentrate on both the things simultaneously. Is there any dry land exercise or any exercis? which will help me to overcome this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility is that you are focusing on your breathing. Once you are comfortable with that, then you can focus on other things.

I would recommend getting a pull buoy for the moment to keep your legs in position so you can work on your breathing. Several things to keep in mind:

1. Turn your head the minimum required. Don’t be looking at the sky or ceiling. Good swimmers almost seem to breathe underwater, using the space behind the head’s bow wave. Until you are fast, that is hard, but over-rotating makes everything else hard.
2. Shoulders should be rotated, so your neck doesn’t have to turn very far at all.
3. From the waist down there should be very little rotation. Do not extend rotate and extend your legs wide horizontally.
4. Once ok with breathing, shift focus to steady arm movement and steady leg kicking. Your stroke rules when you can breathe and does not stop or slow when you do so.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

As a long-time swimmer, I think this is just a coordination issue - a bit like trying to rub your stomach while patting your head. When you think about one part, the other tends to stop until you 'train' your brain to do both.

Rather than using a pull-buoy as suggested by the other answer, I would suggest a different exercise: use a kick board held out in front of you with one arm, and practice using the other arm to pull and breathe to that side (pick the side you find most comfortable breathing on). Kick with your legs the entire time.

Using a kick board in this way has several benefits:

1. Your body will stay flat on the water which makes kicking easier.
2. Doing single arm pull is less to think about so you can focus on the pull-breath-kick mechanic.
3. Additional buoyancy towards your head will make breathing easier.

Once you get used to doing it on your dominant side, switch arms and do the other side (it's important to breathe both sides if you want a balanced stroke), then try doing full stroke again and see if it has helped.